# Product of two numbers which are expressable as the sum of two perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, sums-of-squares

Problem: "**Let m and n be integers such that each can be expressed as the sum of
two perfect squares. Show that mn has this property as well**"

Proof: Let $m =a^2+b^2$ , $n=c^2+d^2$ ,where $a, b , c , d$ are integers. Now consider the product $$z:=(a+bi)(c+di)$$ Note that $$|z|=|(a+bi)||(c+di)|=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}$$Therefore $mn = |z|^2$. But $|z|^2$ will be a sum of squares of integers, since $\Re (z)$ and $\Im(z)$
are integers.

Everything is clear except for the last statement, **"But $|z|^2$ will be a sum of squares of integers, since $\Re (z)$ and $\Im(z)$
are integers."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\lvert z\rvert^2=\operatorname{Re}^2z+\operatorname{Im}^2z.$$On the other hand,$$\operatorname{Re}z=ac-bd\in\mathbb Z\text{ and }\operatorname{Im}z=ad+bc\in\mathbb Z.$$

Answer (score 1):

You will find that

- $z = (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$ with integer real part and integer imaginary part
- so $mn = |z|^2 = (ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$ is the sum of the squares of two integers